# Getting "Error Mounting Filesystem"

Tags: filesystem, disk

I am unable to open my sda4 and sda2 drives. When I check the Disks app I am getting the below errors

sda4: `Error mounting/dev/sda4 at/media/santhosh/Personal: Unknown error when mounting/dev/sda4(udisk-error-quark,0)`

sda2: `Error mounting filesystem`

Comment: Are there any more error messages in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/kern.log`?

Comment: Please [edit] your Question and do: `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`. Are they part of a Windows "Fast Boot" system?